# не проигрывает audio при вызове из JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc

Сайт на asp.net mvc, нужно сделать звуковое сопровождение если новые данные добавились в таблицу. Решил использовать обычный audio html.
На вьюшку добавил

```
<audio id="audio1" controls preload="auto">
<source src="@Url.Action("PlayFile")" type="audio/mp3"/></audio>
```

указывал src через src="~/Music/2.mp3" но аудио не воспроизводилось...

Контроллер:

```
    public FileResult PlayFile()
    {            
        return new FilePathResult(Server.MapPath("~/Music/2.mp3"), "audio/mp3");
    }
```

На форме отобразился контрол Audio и если нажать на кнопку воспроизведения, аудио играет.
Затем для решения задачи, в разделе JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio1'); 
....
....
    if (val.Id > 1000) {     //в некотором месте логики, есть условие, если оно истино мне нужно оповестить звуком
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
    });
```

И здесь появляется для меня непонятная вещь, при загрузке страницы, и при выполнении условия ( к примеру, проверял alert срабатывает), звук не воспроизводится. Но если на странице щелкнуть мышкой на любом объекте, звук начинает воспроизводится. Как будто элемент инициализируется.
Как побороть такое?

Comment: Никак не побороть. Это новая политика хрома. При вызове `audio.play();` у вас в консоли должно быть предупреждение - почитайте его.

Comment: открывается через Оперу. А других вариантов нет? другие контролы/библиотеки тоже не подойдут?

Comment: Нет, библиотеки не помогут. Можете попробовать с `Web Audio API`, но мне кажется, что тоже не поможет.

Comment: Ок,спасибо. на IE/Edge работает

Comment: Да, поскольку, как я написал, это органичение Хрома) В сафари еще может работать будет. А вообще гугл рекомендует показывать в интерфейсе, что звук выключен. И кнопочку включить звук сделать.

Comment: не совсем понял фразу "гугл рекомендует показывать в интерфейсе, что звук выключен. И кнопочку включить звук сделать.",т.е. кнопка нужна чисто так сказать ради инициализации интерфейса? логика нажатия кнопки какая должна быть?

Comment: В целом вы правы - кнопка нужна лишь для того, что бы браузер понял, что пользователь взаимодействует со страницей и готов слушать звук) На кнопке не делать никаких действий особенных.